# c# turning List<char> into a string and displaying in a label in windows form app

Tags: c#, string, forms, list

So I have a list of randomly generated chars and I want to display the contents of the list in a label. `Game.NewPhrase()` generates a new random set of chars and saves them to a list. Here is the code I'm trying to use to get the label to display:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Game.NewPhrase();
    phraseLbl.Text = Game.code.ToString();
}
```

However in the label box the random chars are supposed to appear it says `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Char]`. I'm not sure what that is telling me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `string` constructor accepting array of `char`:

```
phraseLbl.Text = new string(Game.code.ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Gave that a try and it was successful printing out the first letter, however the 9 that are left dont appear(Theres 10 total chars in the list). I tested to see and made sure my method is actually filling it up with 10 and it is.

Comment: @Yummy275 Quite impossible what you are saying. It cannot run differently on your machine, on mine it correctly creates a string. Make sure that `Game.code` is acutally a list with all entries, just put a breakpoint on that line I suggested.

Comment: @Yummy275 does this have null characters in it or something? not that it should matter

Comment: @MichałTurczyn You are correct, I forgot to put the method which actually sets the length of the list lol. Thanks again! It works perfectly now!

Comment: You shouldn't have to set "the length of the list", if you add items to the list, `.ToArray()` should return an array with them all.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `string.Concat`

```
var cs = new char[] {'s','f','f'};
Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(cs));
```

**Output**

```
sff
```

---

However, this is why you **wouldn't** use `string.Concat`

## Benchmarks

Tested 1000 times each scale (size of char array), garbage collected before each run, and the top 75% results counted

```
┌──────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│        Test Mode │ Release (64Bit)                            │
│   Test Framework │ .NET Framework 4.7.1 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000) │
╞══════════════════╪════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ Operating System │ Microsoft Windows 10 Pro                   │
│          Version │ 10.0.17763                                 │
├──────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│       CPU System │ Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz    │
│  CPU Description │ Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 9      │
├──────────────────┼──────────┬──────────────────┬──────────────┤
│  Cores (Threads) │ 4 (8)    │     Architecture │ x64          │
│      Clock Speed │ 3600 MHz │        Bus Speed │ 100 MHz      │
│          L2Cache │ 1 MB     │          L3Cache │ 8 MB         │
└──────────────────┴──────────┴──────────────────┴──────────────┘
```

**Results**

```
┌── Standard input ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Value  │    Average │    Fastest │    Cycles │ Garbage │ Test │         Gain │
├── Scale 10 ───────────────────────────────────────────────────── 0.103 sec ──┤
│ new    │   1.492 µs │ 800.000 ns │   8.408 K │ 0.000 B │ Base │       0.00 % │
│ Concat │   3.128 µs │   1.600 µs │  14.210 K │ 0.000 B │ Pass │    -109.65 % │
├── Scale 100 ──────────────────────────────────────────────────── 0.095 sec ──┤
│ new    │   1.501 µs │ 800.000 ns │   8.474 K │ 0.000 B │ Base │       0.00 % │
│ Concat │   3.772 µs │   2.700 µs │  16.621 K │ 0.000 B │ Pass │    -151.23 % │
├── Scale 1,000 ────────────────────────────────────────────────── 0.098 sec ──┤
│ new    │   1.932 µs │ 800.000 ns │   9.949 K │ 0.000 B │ Base │       0.00 % │
│ Concat │  18.724 µs │  15.400 µs │  70.817 K │ 0.000 B │ Pass │    -868.93 % │
├── Scale 10,000 ───────────────────────────────────────────────── 0.123 sec ──┤
│ new    │   4.843 µs │   1.700 µs │  21.343 K │ 0.000 B │ Base │       0.00 % │
│ Concat │ 143.127 µs │ 140.900 µs │ 518.406 K │ 0.000 B │ Pass │  -2,855.53 % │
├── Scale 100,000 ──────────────────────────────────────────────── 0.306 sec ──┤
│ new    │  14.013 µs │  13.900 µs │  53.592 K │ 0.000 B │ Base │       0.00 % │
│ Concat │   1.421 ms │   1.378 ms │   5.118 M │ 0.000 B │ Pass │ -10,041.75 % │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

**Code**

```
[Test("new", "", true)]
public string Test1(char[] input, int scale)
{
   return new string(input);

}

[Test("Concat", "", false)]
public string Test2(char[] input, int scale)
{
   return string.Concat(input);
}
```

Comment: Impressive! Out of curiosity, how did you get performance details?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn i have been writing my own benchmarker to help me with the work i do (it is designed specifically for the environments i work in), but its tweaked especially for Stackoverflow output :P However i would suggest, [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) its actually better in a lot of ways and a lot more reconfigurable

Comment: Great! Thanks :)